# Insert into view in h2 database

Tags: java, database, jdbc, view, h2

**edit:** I want to add values to a table (paziente) working with a view of that table (viewPaziente) and not directly the table.

**edit2:** Found a stupid mistake in the code, now it does give me an error, but it is not helping:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Feature not supported: "VIEW"; SQL statement:
>   INSERT INTO "viewPaziente" values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) [50100-147]

Is it possible to insert a row in a view of a table?

I mean... I have a table "paziente" with many fields, I've created a view of Paziente and I want to add a row to paziente through the view. Is it possible to do this in H2?

I'm using the following code

```
public static boolean AddAnagrafica(String nome, String cognome, 
        String data, String telefono, String email,String codiceFiscale, boolean isDonna, String indirizzo, String citta, 
        String provincia, String cap, String paese ){
    Connection conn=null;
    try {
         conn = getConnection();
         PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO \"viewPaziente\" values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
         st.setInt(1, new Random().nextInt()); 
         st.setString(2,nome);
         st.setString(3,cognome);
         st.setString(4,data);
         st.setString(5,telefono);
         st.setString(6,email);
         st.setString(7,codiceFiscale);
         st.setBoolean(8,isDonna);
         st.setString(9,indirizzo);
         st.setString(10,citta);
         st.setString(11,provincia);
         st.setString(12,cap);
         st.setString(13,paese);
         st.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm starting to think this is not possible with the h2 database

Comment: oops this feature is not supported.

Comment: It is possible, but you need to implement updating the base table yourself (see my answer below).

Comment: Maybe it's part of your problem: avoid use of `\"` around your table name. Usually, double quote has no meaning in SQL. The simple quote is user to delimit a string (with possible double quote(s) inside). The official "simple quote" is written as `''`. Example : `INSERT INTO my_table (my_text) VALUES ('Double quote=" and, guess what, simple quote=''!')`

Answer (score 7):

In H2, views are not updatable by default. To make them updatable, you need to use an 'instead of' trigger. An example on how to do that [available in the H2 source repository](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/master/h2/src/test/org/h2/samples/UpdatableView.java).

Comment: Link above may be obsolete.  This one works as of 5/2017: http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#updatable_views  and https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/phoenix/phoenix-docs/src/test/org/h2/samples/UpdatableView.java

Comment: Thanks! Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy specific columns to be inserted in to a view through java ,I hope this is what you are looking for, if not let me know.

```
st.executeQuery("insert into viewPaziente(ID, Name, Start_Date) values SELECT id, first_name, sysdate FROM Paziente Where <matching condition>");
```

More Information on Insert ,Update or Delete 
http://sql-plsql.blogspot.com/2009/03/insert-update-delete-views.html

Comment: I want to add values to the table Paziente, using the view not directly the table.

Comment: @MaurizioPZ inserting in to a view , will in turn insert in to table.